# Finite generation of Hom between cyclic and artinian module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring with unit, and $I$ be a nonzero ideal of $R$. Let $M$ be an artinian $R$ module. Is $\operatorname{Hom}(R/I, M)$ finitely generated?

Thanks.

Comment: i  cannot understand how it was tagged as duplicate earlier.

Comment: It was my fault, sorry. At first I didn't read your question properly, resp. had the false impression that your modules are finitely generated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many counterexamples. If $IM=0$, then $\hom(R/I,M)=M$. Now take any artinian $S$-module $M$ which is not finitely generated (for example $\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$), $R:=S \times \mathbb{Z}$, $I=0 \times \mathbb{Z}$.